# Question on solving cubic polynomials

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, cubics

I tried deriving the solutions of a cubic polynomial using a method with which I derived solutions for a quadratic polynomial.

**Here is the method for quadratics:**

Let $P(x) = ax^2+bx+c$. 
The value of $x$ for which $\frac{dP(x)}{dx} = 0$ is $-\frac{b}{2a}$. We will call it $\alpha$. 
It can easily be shown that $P(\alpha+x) = P(\alpha-x)$. Geometrically  it means that $P(x)$ has the line of symmetry $ y=\alpha$. Meaning that the polynomial $P(x+\alpha)$ has the line of symmetry $y=0$ and therefore its solutions are opposite of each other. Which means that $P(x+\alpha) = (x+x_1)(x-x_1) = x^2 - x_1^2$ where $x_1$ and $-x_1$ are its solutions, which can be calculated more easily. Knowing that I made the substitution $x=y+\alpha$ and it resulted in:
$$ P(x) = ay^2+c+\alpha\frac{b}{2} = ay^2+\beta $$

So it follows $$P(x) = 0 \iff ay^2+\beta = 0  \iff  y = \pm\sqrt{-\frac{\beta}{a}} \iff $$

$$ x = \pm\sqrt{-\frac{\beta}{a}} + \alpha = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} $$

**My attempt for cubics:**

$P(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$. The value of $x$ for which $\frac{d^2P(x)}{dx^2} = 0$ is $-\frac{b}{3a}$ which I call $\alpha$. There is the symmetry $P(\alpha+x) = -P(\alpha-x)$So it seems natural to make the substitution $x=y+\alpha$. This leads to :

$$ P(x) = ay^3+y(c+b\alpha )+c\alpha+d   $$

And here I'm stuck.

Comment: There is an exact formula for cubics, but it is quite complicated and requires complex numbers.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula)

Comment: Google ["reduced cubic" + equation](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22reduced+cubic%22+%22equation%22). For a somewhat geometric interpretation of this substitution, see the end of my answer to [The sum - product problem](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/8029/745).

Comment: For cubics one substitution $x=y-\frac{b}{3a}$ is not enough. See my method deriving of the perfect cubic in [Intro](https://vk.com/doc-157804185_494990686?dl=4ac3b4e0130a44745d).